# Filter product attributes by name with PHP?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

Is it possible to get a products attributes collection and filter that by name? I want all attributes of a product that end with `_whatever`.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection() 
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.'_whatever'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want products that have that attribute set. I want to get those attributes from a product that have a name that ends with _whatever. So basically I have a product object and want to go from there.

Comment: which attribute set, you don't want in collection??

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You can Use like this

```
$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$name.'_whatever'.'%'))
            ->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code :

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$name.'_whatever'.'%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

***Try below code to display product object with all attribute***

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.'_whatever'));
```

*IF you don't want specific attribute set in collection use below code*

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.'_whatever'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',array('nin' => array($setId))); //$setId is 4 as example
```